# Why do my images not upload when submitting Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, file-upload, google-chrome-extension, upload

Trying to upload a chrome extension to the web store, I filled all fields out and they are verified, but when I try to submit an image as a screenshot of the program it says 'processing' and is stuck until the connection times out.

How can I fix it?

The error in console.log is

[image: Console Error Message]

Comment: @GauravPingale  Quite specific but I think the reason had to do with file size - I ended up using adobe XD to make exactly the right size as the canvas and that worked.

Comment: Hi @ElliotCullen Thanks for the reply. Turns out I was using larger image size with correct ratio. It needs exact size in pixels as mentioned on the store